# Passing input XML to variable in XSLT with element name

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to map the input XML to variable but it is eliminating all the tag's name passing only the value of the tag.

**Input XML**

```
<Response>
    <FirstName>Manoj</FirstName>
    <LastName>Naik</LastName>
</Response>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
              xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl in lang user f msxsl"
xmlns:in="http://www.composite.net/ns/transformation/input/1.0"
xmlns:lang="http://www.composite.net/ns/localization/1.0"
xmlns:f="http://www.composite.net/ns/function/1.0"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts">
    <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">
        <msxsl:assembly name="System.Data"/>
        <![CDATA[
    public string GetVaribaleData(string text)
        {

           return text;
        }   
    ]]>
    </msxsl:script>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="encdata">
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            <!--<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>-->
      <!--<xsl:copy-of select="*" />-->
      <!-- <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*" /> -->
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="json" select="user:GetVaribaleData($encdata)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the above code in the output variable it is returning `\n\tManoj\n\tNaik\n`

Expected information in the variable `encdata` and parameter present in C# function `text` as below -

```
<Response>
    <FirstName>Manoj</FirstName>
    <LastName>Naik</LastName>
</Response>
```

I want to pass the Input XML along with element name to `encdata` present in the XSLT. I want to use that variable in C# code to do further processing on the same.

Is there any way to do the same?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve here. Rather than show how you are trying to solve this problem, can you explain what the problem you are trying to solve is, as I am not sure you to use a vendor-specific function here. It would help if you showed the output you expect to get in this case. Thank you!

Comment: Which XSLT processor is that that you use? The use of `msxsl:script language="C#"` suggests it is Microsoft's `XslCompiledTransform` but the use of `version="3.0"` doesn't seem to make sense in that case as Microsoft only supports XSLT 1.0. As for passing XML around between XSLT and C#, that depends on the particular processor, with Microsoft you can write a function taking an `XPathDocument` or an `XPathNodeIterator` as the argument.

Comment: See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/script-blocks-using-msxsl-script#script-functions for the mapping of XSLT/XPath types like node-set or result tree fragment to certain .NET types in case you use `XslCompiledTransform`.

Comment: @TimC I have updated the Question and mentioned expected output.

Comment: Is your expected output the same as your input? You have defined a variable named `json`? Are you perhaps trying to convert XML to json?

Comment: If the processor is `XslCompiledTransform` then you can use `GetVaribaleData(XPathNavigator node) {  // here you can use the XPathNavigator API to further process the passed in XML, not as a string but as an XPathNavigator object }`

Comment: @TimC I want to capture whatever XML input I am passing to XSLT in one variable and want to pass that data to C# script to do further processing.

Comment: @TimC This is just sample code. I don't want to convert input to JSON.

Comment: You probably want to define the variable as `<xsl:variable name="encdata" select="Response">` in this case, and change the `GetVaribaleData` method to use XPathNavigator as Martin describes.

Comment: @MartinHonnen TimC Thanks for your help :). I am doing it as per the suggestions of the MartinHonnen

Answer (score 0):

This was too long to write in comments, but do you really need to use a C# function there, which will tie your code to a specific processor? Perhaps you can achieve the same in pure XSLT, using a named template?

For example, try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:in="http://www.composite.net/ns/transformation/input/1.0"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.composite.net/ns/localization/1.0"
    xmlns:f="http://www.composite.net/ns/function/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="in lang f">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template name="GetVariableData">
        <xsl:param name="node" />
        <xsl:param name="name" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$node/*[local-name() = $name]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="encdata" select="Response" />
        <xsl:call-template name="GetVariableData">
            <xsl:with-param name="node" select="$encdata" />
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'LastName'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```